# Async Components in Angular w/Webpack Code-Splitting

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, vue.js, modal-dialog

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help answer this question. In the past, I've used Webpack code-splitting in Vue similar to what's seen [in this video](https://youtu.be/R2J9cTtlBXI?t=11m58s). It's super simple and you just use Webpack's import method by doing something like:

```
const myComponent = () => import('/path/to/myComponent');
```

I'm trying to do something similar in Angular 5.2 (or later). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Specifically, I'm trying to code-split a modal into its own bundle, then lazy load that bundle so that it's not loaded on the initial view. I only really need it once the actual button is clicked. Here is what this looks like:

```
this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  // dialog component details
});
```

I've tried things like:

```
import('./DialogComponent').then(component => {
  const DialogComponent = component;
    this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      // dialog component details
   });
});
```

But it didn't really work. I can sort of get the component, but I keep getting type errors from TypeScript. I also tried:

```
async componentMethod() {
  const DialogComponent = await import('./DialogueComponent');
    this.dialogue.open(DialogComponent, {
      // dialog component details
   });
});
```

Edit: Here's the error I'm getting:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof import('/path/to/component')' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{}> | TemplateRef<{}>'.
  Type 'typeof '/path/to/component' is not assignable to type 'TemplateRef<{}>'.
    Property 'elementRef' is missing in type 'typeof '/path/to/component'.

Comment: What this has to do with Vue.js?

Comment: Please add the errors.

Comment: Vue.js natively supports async components, so the above method works there. I'm trying to replicate this effect in Angular.